SQL Backups with SQL 2022 Contained Availability Group
We have a SQL 2022 Always On Availabilty Group with Contained databases; a new feature in this version of SQL. The master and msdb databases are now also in the Avalability Group. We like this setup, for example we only have to maintain the logins that exists in the master database of the AG and not on both the SQL servers.
Because of this setup, we can make SQL backups on the primairy, secondary server or within Contained the availability group. We tried different options and we could always restore the database and transaction logs if we made a full backup in the Contained Availability group mixed with   transaction log backups from the SQL servers. I searched the web but couldn't find any best-practices and known issues that we can encounter if we make the SQL backup in the Contained Availability Group.
Has anyone more information or experience about this subject?
Regards, Jeroen Bleeker
